# c# datetime to string for default values

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I've read quite a few threads about nullable `DateTime` and string formatting.

In my case, I "simply" want to to differentiate `default(DateTime)`, i.e. `DateTime.MinValue` from any other value when converting to string. Output should be the result of following logic:

```
string res = myDateTime == DateTime.MinValue ? string.Empty : myDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I know that for numbers, we have a very convenient way to define what to display depending on the value - we can handle positive, negative and 0 values differently, and even better, display mask applies rounding, i.e.

```
String.Format("{0:#,#####0.00;#;#}", 0.001)
```

will display an empty string, which is just exactly what I'd like to have for dates. So is there one such magic formatting string around? Or any other workaround?

Comment: A constructed DateTime will default to Jan 1, 1900.  So testing for this is the best workaround.  Often people test for < Jan 1, 1970 or something similar.

Comment: You can create an extension method.

Comment: @jdweng - A constructed `DateTime` defaults to year 1, not year 1900.

Comment: @Max I know about extension methods, but I'm affraid I cannot use them as an override, can I ??

Comment: You cannot override ToString but you can generate a new method like this: `public static string ToStringEx(this DateTime value) 
{
 return value == DateTime.MinValue ? string.Empty : myDateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}` Optionally you can pass additional argument as format string

Comment: @Max indeed - unfortunately this won't help me as I need to format the string via a provided control that accepts only the format string as parameter...

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be asking about [the `;` section separator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SectionSeparator) - which is valid for custom numeric format strings.  There's nothing magic about it.  It has a specific implementation, which only works on numeric data types.  Unfortunately, there is no similar separator token available in the [custom date and time format strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

If you use a nullable type, `DateTime?` you will get the output you're looking for without any conditional logic.

```
DateTime? dt;
string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt)  // ""

dt = DateTime.Now;
string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt)  // "03/29/2017"
```

But without nullables, you have to use conditional logic.

```
DateTime dt;
string.Format("{0}", dt == default(DateTime) ? "" : dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
```